# Iterating over a list of classes

Tags: c++

I want to be able to iterate over a list of classes that inherit from a common ancestor.

Minified version of what I want (Python-like syntax as that's the language I'm coming from):

```
const *Player *PLAYERS[3] = { *PlayerTypeOne, *PlayerTypeTwo, *PlayerTypeThree};

int outcome = 0;

for player in players {
    if (doThingWithPlayer((&player)(), some, other, variables) == true) {
        outcome++;
    }
}
```

If this is not the preferred way of doing this sort of operation, advice on how I should continue is very welcome.

The sort of code I want to avoid is:

```
int outcome = 0;

PlayerTypeOne player_one();
if doThingWithPlayer(player_one, some, other, variables){
    outcome++;
}
PlayerTypeTwo player_two();
if doThingWithPlayer(player_two, some, other, variables){
    outcome++;
}
PlayerTypeThree player_three();
if doThingWithPlayer(player_three, some, other, variables){
    outcome++;
}
```

Comment: A list of classes or a list of class instances (i.e. objects)?

Comment: do you mix up the terms `object` and `class`?

Comment: @NPE A list of classes

Comment: @muddyfish in what format is this list of classes?

Comment: It can be in whatever format, I just want to be able to do a consistant thing with multiple classes without a load of copy and pasting

Comment: @muddyfish: Fair enough (although I can't shake off the feeling that there's an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) lurking in here).

Comment: @NPE I feel there is as well which is why I said I was open to other approaches

Comment: @muddyfish: But we still don't know what's the *actual problem* you're trying to solve with the "iterate over classes" approach. There's any number of ways your code can be rewritten in idiomatic C++; it's hard to recommend one without knowing the end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [factory design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):

```
Player *create_by_name(const std::string &what)
{
   if (what == "PlayerTypeOne")
         return new PlayerTypeOne;
   if (what == "PlayerTypeTwo")
         return new PlayerTypeTwo;

   // ...
}
```

and so on. What you also appear to want to do is to supply parameters to each subclass's constructors.

If all subclasses take the same constructor parameters, this becomes trivial: pass the parameters to the factory, and just have them forwarded to the constructors.

If you need to support different parameters to constructors, this becomes more complicated. I would suggest that you start small, and implement a simple factory for your objects, with no constructor parameters, or with just a couple of them that are the same for all subclasses. Once you have the basic principles working, then you can worry about handling the complicated corner cases.

Then, just have an array of class names, iterate over the array, and call the factory. This should have similar results as your pseudo-Python code.

Answer (score 1):

C++ provides no built-in introspection, so you can't just obtain objects that represent your classes and create instances with them.

What you can do is use metaprogramming:

```
// A list of types
template <class...> struct pack { };

// Calls f with one default-constructed instance of each T
template <class... Ts, class F>
void construct_each(pack<Ts...>, F &&f) {

    // Classic pre-C++17 expansion trick
    using ex = int[];
    (void)ex{(f(Ts{}), void(), 0)..., 0};

    // C++17 version
    // (void)(f(Ts{}), ...);
}

// ...

using Players = pack<PlayerTypeOne, PlayerTypeTwo, PlayerTypeThree>;

void foo() {
    int outcome = 0;

    construct_each(Players{}, [&](auto &&player) {
        if(doThingWithPlayer(player, some, other, variables))
            ++outcome;
    });
}
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07050849d7a3aa69)